# How to compute frequency distribution in R?

Tags: r

Actually there are many functions which I don't know what to use to calculate it

```
X = rnorm(100)
```

Lets assume I have a normally distributed vector called X. I don't know anything about bin centre and I want to calculate the frequency distribution for X

As an output I want to have one vector of frequency and one vector as bin Centres 
I think calculating bin centre can be done like

```
seq(min(mat[,1]),max(mat[,1]), by=0.01 )
```

Can you please guide me to calculate it and obtain the needed output? which function I must use ?

example data

```
0.0014985
0.0087414
0.011304
0.011619
0.013201
0.017573
0.018898
0.022491
0.023001
0.024195
0.024434
0.024469
0.028859
0.031385
0.031647
0.032224
0.033946
0.036938
0.037867
0.037993
0.038889
0.038922
0.03894
0.041474
0.041804
0.044066
0.044082
0.044962
0.047495
```

With Prism I obtain the following (bin width is 0.05)

```
bin centres   frequency
    0           1
    0.005       0
    0.01        3
    0.015       1
    0.02        3
    0.025       4
    0.03        4
    0.035       2
    0.04        7
    0.045       4
    0.05        0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use R’s hist function (see `?hist`):

```
h <- hist(X);
```

The bin centres are given by

```
h$mids
```

and the counts by

```
h$counts
```

Normalised counts are then simply
`h$counts / sum(h$counts)`.

You can specify the bins using the breaks argument (either by specifying the number of bins, or by given the bins directly).

By the way, the same can be achieved using R’s cut and table functions (see `?cut`, `?table`).

Comment: thanks but it is not what I really want. if I want to do that for 100 vectors and I want the same bin cancers for all, then it is useless. I shared a real data. Look at it, please look at my seq I gave, it is with distance of 0.01 , I want to be able to manipulate bin centres

Comment: I’m not sure what the problem is.
As I said, you can specify bins explicitly using breaks (either within hist or within cut). This will allow you to use the same bins for all data.

For example in your case, you can do
`breaks <- seq(round(min(X)), round(max(X)), by = 0.01);`
`h <- hist(X, breaks = breaks);`

You just need to make sure that the breaks span the entire range of x.

Comment: look at an example I showed above. I calculate the frequency distribution with Prism and i showed the results. but with R, I cannot reproduce this ,

Comment: Of course you can. I strongly suggest reading the R help to hist and cut, specifically the part on how to specify the breaks argument.
To reproduce your example (that keeps changing by the way), you need to do
`breaks <- seq(0, 0.055, by = 0.005) - 0.0025;`
`h <- hist(x, breaks = breaks);`
`print(h$mids);`
`[1] 0.000 0.005 0.010 0.015 0.020 0.025 0.030 0.035 0.040 0.045 0.050`
`print(h$counts);`
`[1] 1 0 3 1 3 4 4 2 7 4 0`

Comment: The key here is the breaks argument. Prism gives you a 0 bin centre, which would mean that the bin spans the x values [-0.0025, +0.0025]. This might not be very meaningful; but you can reproduce this in R with the breaks I specify above.

Comment: you are right!!! the count is the frequency values ? and the mids are the bin centres ?

Comment: That's correct. By the way, you can see all values (breaks, counts = "frequency", mids = "bin centres" etc.) that are stored in the histogram object if you do a `str(h)`.

Comment: THANKS I really appreciate your help, actually one ore question and I accept your answer . I want to make a nonlinear regression Gaussian curve fit between counts and mids, I found that I can use xls function but I don't know how to do it, do you have any idea ? I can simply do this in Prism but in R

Comment: @nik This is a different question, mostly off-topic if you are only interested in "How to do it in R". Such a question would be a better fit for Stack Overflow if you can provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @chl you are right! I accepted the answer and I post a question there . thanks again